# Set X Minutes in Python Time Modules But Want Background Process

Tags: python, multithreading, time, raspberry-pi, sleep

** i want to set x minute but without sleep or delay because i want to reset every x Minute esp32 reset Pin But want background process in Python **

```
import time
def SetTime(X):
start=time.gmtime().tm_sec
time.sleep(1)
count=0
while True:
if start==time.gmtime().tm_sec:
count+=1
print("1 min is Over")
start = time.gmtime().tm_sec
time.sleep( 1 )
if count==X:
break
SetTime(5)
```

without using sleep or time delay

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the shown code. (2) Maybe you want a "cron job".

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `threading`, remember to check shared state if you have multiple threads that are reading and writing the same variables.

For your example it will be:

```
import time
import threading

def set_time(X):
    start = time.time()
    count = 0
    while True:
        if time.time() - start >= 60:
            count += 1
            print("1 min is Over")
            start = time.time()

        if count == X:
            break

t = threading.Thread(target=set_time, args=(5,))
t.start()
```